# Modify column output for sqlform.grid() in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have started using web2py for a web application and try to use `SQLFORM.grid(...)` to display a paginated listing of one of my db-table's data like in the following minimal example.

```
grid=SQLFORM.grid(query,
    links=links,
    fields=[db.example.date,db.example.foo, db.example.bar])
```

The `db.example.date` field contains a Python datetime.datetime object in UTC. At the moment it is displayed just plainly like that. However, I want to have more control about the actual output in a way that I can set the local timezone and modify the output string to have something like "2 hours ago".

As seen in another question[0] I can use the `links` to insert new columns. Unfortunately I can't seem to sort the rows by a field I have inserted in such way. Also, they are inserted on the right instead of actually replacing my first column. So that does not seem to be a solution.

To sum it up: How do I gain control about the way `db.example.date` is printed out in the end?

[0] [Calculated Fields in web2py sqlgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232336/calculated-fields-in-web2py-sqlgrid)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your goal when you define the table in your model.  The represent parameter in the Field constructor that you used in define_table will be recognized by the SQLFORM.grid.  For example, if you wanted to just print the date with the month name you could put the following in your model.

```
Field('a_date', type='date', represent=lambda x, row: x.strftime("%B %d, %Y")),
```

your function could also convert to local time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use prettydate to change the datetime arid format in a humanized string, and call it in the represent parameter of your Field() descriptor. For example :

```
from gluon.tools import prettydate
db.example.date.represent = lambda v,r: prettydate(r.date)
```

That way, any display of the db.example.date would be displayed humanized, including through SQLFORM.grid

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the date always represented in this way as per David Nehme's answer. Just before your grid creation, you can set the db.table.field.represent in the controller.

```
db.example.date.represent = lambda value, row: value.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

followed by.

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(query,....
```

I use this often when I join tables. If there is a row.field in the represent from the model file it breaks because it then must be more specific, row.table.field.